# Getting only the most recent records from ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, distinct-values

I have a user index of ElasticSearch where each user has a name and multiple other user related information and also an **indexedAt** field which specify when the user information is being indexed. When any information of user changes I create a new record of the user and store it. Therefore each user can have many multiple records in the index.

Now Simply I want to get only the most up to date information of the queried users.
For example if I run the following query, it will return all of the records of John and Smith. But I want only the most recent record for each of the users.

```
{
  "size": 10000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "name": "John"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "name": "Smith"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "indexedAt": {
      "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: And what would happen if you used the size as parameter? (aka POST /yourPath?size=1)

Comment: I guess setting the size to 1 will return only 1 record where I need one record for each user. So for the given example I need two records. The user number can be any, so limitting the size probably wont be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inner_hits` to get your answer

```
GET /temp_index/_search
{
  "size": 10, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "name": "John"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "name": "Smith"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "name.keyword",
    "inner_hits": {
      "name": "most_recent",
      "size": 1,
      "sort": [{"indexedAt": "desc"}]
    }
  }
}
```

This will get you a result similar to below

```
{
    "_index" : "temp_index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "KSHBjnMBPr3VGlJjXe3d",
    "_score" : 0.8266786,
    "_source" : {
      "name" : "John",
      "indexedAt" : 1015
    },
    "fields" : {
      "name.keyword" : [
        "John"
      ]
    },
    "inner_hits" : {
      "most_recent" : {
        "hits" : {
          "total" : {
            "value" : 3,
            "relation" : "eq"
          },
          "max_score" : null,
          "hits" : [
            {
              "_index" : "temp_index",
              "_type" : "_doc",
              "_id" : "LyHBjnMBPr3VGlJji-24",
              "_score" : null,
              "_source" : {
                "name" : "John",
                "indexedAt" : 1050
              },
              "sort" : [
                1050
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

You can access the `inner_hits` portion to get the document which was most recently indexed (i.e. with the largest `indexedAt` value)